# Orbital Approximation

Tags: physical-chemistry

We determined the hydrogen wavefunctions exactly, and the orbital approximation says that we approximate the orbitals of multi-electron atoms with hydrogen wavefunctions. How do we know that this is an okay approximation to make? How much error is there in assuming this?

Comment: no we don't approximate multi-electron atoms with hydrogen wavefunctions, we model them with gaussian basis functions that somewhat resemble hydrogen atoms. In the limit of infinite basis functions the approximation for the true shape of the molecular orbital is exact.

Comment: We know it is kind of OK because it kind of works out. Until it doesn't, of course. Which causes the many questions here about the transition metals and $d$-orbitals and why they aren't all behaving just like a hydrogen atom says they should.